# CGPathCreateMutableCopy/BezierPath from CGPath doesn't fill original

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want accomplish what [this demo does](https://s3.amazonaws.com/coeverywhere-prod-static/public/video/product-demo.webm) but for iOS. Essentially, stroke a path and fill it as it's being stroked, without a closing line.

My approach as it stands now is on `touchesMoved`, move a `CGPath` variable to the the previous point and stroke a line to the current point. Then, call `setNeedsDisplay` wherein I do:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    guard let strokePath = self.strokePath else {
        return
    }
    if let firstPoint = self.points.value.first {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // 1.
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.strokeColor.CGColor)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor.CGColor)
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth)

        // 2.
        let path = UIBezierPath(CGPath: strokePath)

        // 3.
        path.addLineToPoint(firstPoint)

        // 4.
        CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath)
        CGContextDrawPath(context, .EOFill)
        CGContextAddPath(context, strokePath)
        CGContextDrawPath(context, .Stroke)

    }
}
```

1. I set all the path properties such as line width, line cap, etc
2. I create a bezier path from the original stroked path
3. I add a line back to the first point
4. I add both paths to the context and draw them filling one and stroking the other.

The stroke path strokes just how I want it but the copied path only fills from the last point in the original path to the first point that I add the line too. What I want is it to fill the whole thing, including all the points in the copied path. If I manually build up the new path (which becomes wildly inefficient the longer the user draws) like so:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(firstPoint)
for point in self.points.value {
    path.addLineToPoint(point)
}
path.addLineToPoint(firstPoint)
```

The path is filled correctly and looks like this:

[image]

which is precisely the effect I'm trying to achieve. However I can't figure out why copying the path and then adding the final point only strokes the new additions, not the entire path. I've tried it with both a `UIBezierPath` and using `CGPathCreateMutableCopy` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like you've made this more complicated than it should be.

This class lets me draw on a view in a way that matches your linked video, and allows for a drawing that matches your example.

```
class SDDFilledSketchView: UIView {

    var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil
    var tracePath: UIBezierPath? = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action:"handlePan:")
        if (panRecognizer != nil) {
            self.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)
        }
    }

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchPoint = recognizer.locationInView(self)

        if recognizer.state == .Began {
            tracePath = UIBezierPath.init()
            tracePath?.lineWidth = 5
            tracePath?.lineCapStyle = .Round
            tracePath?.moveToPoint(touchPoint)
        } else {
            tracePath?.addLineToPoint(touchPoint)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
        if tracePath != nil {
            tracePath?.fill()
            tracePath?.stroke()
        }
    }

}
```

This is storing the user's path in a UIBezierPath without having to recreate it as they go, it will just add a line to the path as the user moves their finger and let drawRect do the fill and stroke.